# Am I calling Dask dataframe.corr() correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, dask, correlation

I am trying to calculate correlation matrix on Dask dataframe.

1. Data is really huge - around `1 000 000` rows with `900` columns.
2. I want to create a heatmap from the correlation matrix.
3. I know that the heat map will probably be completely confusing and not visually pleasing but still I wanna do it.

I am using Dask `dataframe` to get advantage of `parallelism` so it can be computed faster:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as df

#Create cluster on local machine
client = Client(n_workers = 4, threads_per_worker = 1, memory_limit = '4GB')
client

#Get the data to RAM memory
dataframe_numerical = df.read_csv(numerical_path, engine = 'c', low_memory = False, dtype = dtypes)
dataframe_numerical = dataframe_numerical.persist()

#Calculate the correlation matrix:
corelation = dataframe_numerical.corr().compute()
```

But it has been stuck for so such a long time at this stage in the `Dask` visualization:

- I can still see that the memory in each worker is changing but the tasks for `corr-chunk-read-csv` progress bar hasn't moved at all (progress bar in the middle).
  [image]

**Is my code correct?**

- I am kind of confused if I am calling the `.persist()` and
  `.compute()` method correctly?

---

### Additional info:

- I am using Jupyter Notebook.
- I am not getting any warnings about not enough memory etc.
- My notebook has 16GB of RAM memory
- If I just read the `.csv` file and store it into a Pandas `dataframe` it can fit into my RAM memory and occupies around `2.4GB`.

Code for reading the `.csv` file and storing it into Pandas `dataframe` (this takes around 2 minutes):

```
dataframe_numerical_lazy = df.read_csv(numerical_path, engine = 'c', low_memory = False, dtype = dtypes)
dataframe_numerical = dataframe_numerical_lazy.compute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to compute the correlation matrix is with `numpy` (completes in about 20 seconds):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
num_cols = 10**3
num_rows = 10**6
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(num_rows, num_cols), columns=map(str, range(num_cols)))
data = df.to_numpy()
corrmat = np.corrcoef(data.T)
```

The more important question is why `dask` struggles with this task... I hope there is an answer to that, but if the number of columns was smaller, then dask computes the correlations, try setting low values for `num_cols` and then see at which point your machine stops:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
num_cols = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**6, num_cols), columns=map(str, range(num_cols)))

import dask.dataframe as dd
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

from distributed import Client
client = Client()
client

ddf.corr().compute()
```

Comment: I run into that this question myself and tested your solution. Calculating np.corrcoef runs in about 6s for me. While I had to stop the Dask solution after ~1hour

Comment: > "I hope there is an answer to that..."
As per answer above, the dask snippet above is not a scalable solution.