# How to calculate a correlation matrix in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some code in pandas that I am looking to convert to pyspark. However, my pyspark code keeps running without finishing.

Here is my pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
def get_ld_matrix():
    ld_data = pd.read_csv(f"{target}_locus_UKBB.txt.raw", delim_whitespace=True)
    ld_data = ld_data.drop(columns=["FID", "IID", "PAT", "MAT", "SEX", "PHENOTYPE"])
    ld_matrix = ld_data.corr(method='pearson')
    return ld_data, ld_matrix
ld_data, ld_matrix= get_ld_matrix()
```

Here is the code I've tried rewriting to pyspark that isn't working:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

def get_ld_matrix():
    """Calculates the LD matrix based on the LD data from PLINK using PySpark"""

    ld_data = spark.read.csv(f"{target}_locus_UKBB.txt.raw", sep=" ", header=True, inferSchema=True)
    drop_list = ["FID", "IID", "PAT", "MAT", "SEX", "PHENOTYPE"]
    ld_data = ld_data.drop(*drop_list)
    for col in ld_data.columns:
        ld_data = ld_data.withColumn(col, ld_data[col].cast("float"))

    print('Calculating LD correlation matrix...')

    vec_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=ld_data.columns, outputCol="features")
    ld_data_vector = vec_assembler.transform(ld_data).select("features")
    ld_matrix = Correlation.corr(ld_data_vector, "features").collect()[0][0]

    print('Finished calculating LD correlation matrix')
    return ld_data, ld_matrix

ld_data, ld_matrix = get_ld_matrix()
```

My pyspark code seems to just keep running. I am switching to pyspark to try to speed up the process. What is going wrong with my code?

For reference my input `ld_data` is a matrix of shape `(10000, 6167)` and its contents are just zeros and ones. I can't share my actual data, but an example dataframe would look like:

```
ld_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(5, 5)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code with suggestion for generating random data and it works. Here's the python code and the correlation matrix visualized as image  output.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.stat import Correlation
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

def get_ld_matrix():
    """Calculates the LD matrix based on the LD data from PLINK using PySpark"""

    #ld_data = spark.read.csv(f"{target}_locus_UKBB.txt.raw", sep=" ", header=True, inferSchema=True)
    ld_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(10, 10)) )
    ld_data = spark.createDataFrame(ld_data)

    #drop_list = ["FID", "IID", "PAT", "MAT", "SEX", "PHENOTYPE"]
    #ld_data = ld_data.drop(*drop_list)
    for col in ld_data.columns:
        ld_data = ld_data.withColumn(col, ld_data[col].cast("float"))

    print('Calculating LD correlation matrix...')

    vec_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=ld_data.columns, outputCol="features")
    ld_data_vector = vec_assembler.transform(ld_data).select("features")
    ld_matrix = Correlation.corr(ld_data_vector, "features").collect()[0][0]

    print('Finished calculating LD correlation matrix')
    return ld_data, ld_matrix

ld_data, ld_matrix = get_ld_matrix()


print("ld_matrix is DenseMatrix")
print(ld_matrix)

# Converting the densematrix to pandas Dataframe to plot the values
rows = ld_matrix.toArray().tolist()
df_matrix = pd.DataFrame(rows)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,5))
sns.heatmap(df_matrix,
            xticklabels=df_matrix.columns.values,
            yticklabels=df_matrix.columns.values,  cmap="Greens", annot=True)


plt.show()
```

Output :

Here's the correlation plot using answer given here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73221170/3238085

[image]

You can make the calculations faster by using the solution mentioned in this SO post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66944821/3238085

```
# Setup
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30, 30))


pd_df = pd.DataFrame(np.corrcoef(df.values, rowvar=False), columns=df.columns)


plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5))
sns.heatmap(pd_df,
            xticklabels=pd_df.columns.values,
            yticklabels=pd_df.columns.values,  cmap="Greens", annot=True)
plt.show()
```

Output Image :

[image]

Third way to make the calculations faster is by using a distributed library like Dask or Ray as mentioned in this Datascience Stackexchange answer.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/116357/how-do-you-speed-up-the-calculation-of-a-correlation-matrix-on-a-large-dataset-i

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from dask.distributed import Client
    import dask.dataframe as ddf
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    #Create cluster on local machine
    client = Client(n_workers = 16, threads_per_worker = 4, memory_limit = '24GB')


    # Setup
    np.random.seed(42)

    #Get the data to RAM memory
    pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 50))

    dataframe_numerical = ddf.from_pandas(pandas_df, npartitions=30)

    dataframe_numerical = dataframe_numerical.persist()

    #Calculate the correlation matrix:
    corelation = dataframe_numerical.corr().compute()

    # Setup
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5))
    sns.heatmap(corelation,
                xticklabels=corelation.columns.values,
                yticklabels=corelation.columns.values,  cmap="Greens", annot=True)
    plt.show()
```

Output Image :

[image]